# Ubuntu/Linux 20.04 Raid1 Bios Struggles

Tags: boot, 20.04, raid, bios

So, I am trying to do a RAID 1 on a server that I have build and I've seen a couple different YouTube videos. Probably me being dumb, but can't seem to figure out how to do a RAID 1 on 2x SSDs. Currently Ubuntu 20.04 is on a SSD that of course, boots up Ubuntu. Trying to mirror the SSD onto another SSD so that if the main boot is either dead or so, then it can still run perfectly fine going into the 2nd SSD. I cant seem to figure it out. So my last resort would be to ask the public for more information lol. I've tried messing with "nvme0n1" but nothing. So unsure what im doing wrong. Info in pictures might help that I posted. Any info would assist!

[These are my current drives, my main boot is on nvme0n1, while I want to mirror onto nvme1n1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOY6V.png)

[Disk; main boot SSD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1Wtl.png)

[Disk; 2nd SSD that I would like to mirror onto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXobd.png)

I appreciate the assistance! I used shred to clear out my nvme1n1 to do a fresh start. Trying to start from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

first of all there are two types of RAID: hardware and software. The earlier requires your server to include extra hardware like a raid card or it is sometimes included directly in the motherboard. In general you can configure it through the BIOS and this will be transparent for the OS during install. Ensure your server supports it in the documentation. As for soft RAID, linux uses [mdadm](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mdadm) which requires configuration during the installation process.